# Reference to pgfplot with margincap

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing, marginpar

I was using references to parts of a `pgfplots` plot, which worked perfectly. However, when I changed the document to use `margincap`s, this breaks: I get a warning that one reference is undefined, and the second one just prints as an empty string, without even a warning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mcaption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{margincap} % <- comment me!
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[mark=star,only marks] coordinates {(0, 0)};
\label{plt:a}

\addplot[only marks] coordinates {(1, 1)};
\label{plt:b}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{margincap} % <- comment me!
\end{figure}

`\ref{plt:a}', `\ref{plt:b}'

\end{document}
```

Commenting out the `\begin{margincap}` and its corresponding `end`, everything is ok again... Unfortunately, I have no idea how I could fix this.

[image]

Comment: `mcaption` and `pgfplots` fight each other in redefining `\label`. You lose. `:-(`

Comment: @greg: Do you see any chance for a workaround? It's just this single case in my thesis, and I'd hate to lose `mcaption` over this.

Comment: If it's just this single case, then use directly the asterisk and the bullet instead of `\ref{plt:a}` and `\ref{plt:b}`.

Comment: @egreg: now, this might be a dumb question, but how do I get those symbols? The bullet and `$\bullet$` look the same, but `$\ast$` looks different from what `pgfplots` produces...

Comment: `$\star$` should be the good one

Comment: `$\star$` is much closer, but still not quite there. However, using `marks=text,text mark={$\star$}` I was able to change `pgfplots` to match it `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As egreg already said, this is an incompatibility between `mcaption` and `pgfplots`.

You may want to consider the following workaround:

```
`\pgfplotsplotfromname{plt:a}`, `\pgfplotsplotfromname{plt:b}'
```

instead of `\ref{plt:a}...` will produce the small images as expected.

---

In addition to that work-around, I have just added support to `pgfplots` such that it will work together with `mcaption`. The updated version of pgfplots arrives at the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
\begin{margincap} % <- comment me!

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot[mark=star,only marks] coordinates {(0, 0)};
\label{plt:a}

\addplot[only marks] coordinates {(1, 1)};
\label{plt:b}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\label{X}
\caption{X}
\end{margincap} % <- comment me!
\end{figure}

`\ref{plt:a}', `\ref{plt:b}'

X = \ref{X}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe this is what one wants. Let me know if it looks unexpected.

Comment: This looks just as I expected it to, thanks!